# Modifying the inner CSS of ngx-charts

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-charts

When I spun up the ngx-charts [Advanced Pie Chart example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-pie-chart-advanced), my legend's numbers get cut off. Digging into the CSS, this seems to be because of a `margin-top` being set to `-6px`:

[image: Bad advanced pie chart legend]

After experimenting in the browser, I've found that `10px` makes things look as I'd like. So in the component's CSS, I added:

```
.advanced-pie-legend.legend-items-container.legend-items.legend-item .item-value {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

However, this doesn't affect the CSS of the legend items at all. I've tried variations on `!important`, `::ng-deep` and more, but nothing I do seems to affect that CSS.

**How can I modify the CSS of the `legend-item` so that it will have the proper margin?**

Below is my full component to reproduce the screenshot:

---

**`pietest.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pietest',
  templateUrl: './pietest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pietest.component.css']
})
export class PietestComponent {

  view: any[] = [1000, 500];

  single: any[] = [
    {
      "name": "Germany",
      "value": 8940000
    },
    {
      "name": "USA",
      "value": 5000000
    },
    {
      "name": "France",
      "value": 7200000
    },
      {
      "name": "UK",
      "value": 6200000
    }
  ];

  // options
  gradient: boolean = true;
  showLegend: boolean = true;
  showLabels: boolean = true;
  isDoughnut: boolean = false;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  constructor() { }
}
```

**`pietest.component.html`**

```
<ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart
  [view]="view"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  [results]="single"
  [gradient]="gradient"
  >
</ngx-charts-advanced-pie-chart>
```

**`pietest.component.css`**

```
.advanced-pie-legend.legend-items-container.legend-items.legend-item .item-value {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem doesn't occur in "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^9.0.0". However if you want to change the style in your version to solve this, use the code below in your `pietest.component.scss`.

```
/deep/ .advanced-pie-legend /deep/ .legend-items-container /deep/ .legend-items /deep/ 
.legend-item /deep/ .item-value {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

Please be reminded that the code above will apply to your whole application that match the rule since it's not encapsulated within your component anymore when you use `/deep/` and it is similar with putting the code below into your `style.scss`.

```
.advanced-pie-legend .legend-items-container .legend-items.legend-item .item-value {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yup, this did it. How do you know that this doesn't occur in `^9.0.0`? Is this a known bug? And if so, can you point me to the issue on GitHub?

Comment: Because i am using ^9.0.0, and I've pasted your sample code into my application and it just worked fine. Not sure if anyone had reported this issue.

Comment: Is there anyway this cold be done with the .css type stylesheet? i cant use the scss just to the component i have used this while all others are in css, or would end up changing everything to scss which i am little reluctant to do at the moment...

Comment: you can add the second code of my answer into your styles.css instead of style.scss. Or you can add encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None into your component as pointed out by Ali Safari.

Answer (score 1):

This code should eliminate the CSS component encapsulation so you can overwrite your style

add 
`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`
to `@Component` section in `pietest.component.ts` file.